# how to install rpy2 with anaconda installation of python 3 to run R and Python in same jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 in anaconda installation of python using the command

`pip install rpy2`

and I am getting an error as below

Collecting rpy2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/e0/7da849bb6cf47466ceb28a75f930e61c311878882c275dfb4bbb4fdcc3cb/rpy2-3.2.0.tar.gz

ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

anaconda version -- anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2)
jupyter notebook version -- 6.0.0
python version --3.7.3

Is there another easy way to get rpy2 installed without having to reinstall anaconda or modify other packages ??

Thanks.

Comment: there is an rpy2 package in conda-forge: `conda install -c conda-forge rpy2`. But be aware that conda also ships R, so you may have to reinstall R packages.